# Konva vue js text slide into stage and then stop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, konvajs

Hi I'm using konva js (https://konvajs.org) with vue and I'm trying to animate the text so that it slides into the screen from off the stage to a certain position, however I'm not 100% sure how this should work, I've been able to get a demo working here;

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-konva-template-i2em3

Vue;

```
  <v-stage ref="stage" :config="stageSize">
    <v-layer ref="layer">
      <v-text
        ref="text1"
        :config="{
            text: 'Draggable Text',
            x: 50,
            y: 50,
            draggable: true,
            fill: 'black'
          }"
      />
    </v-layer>
  </v-stage>
</template>


<script>
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      stageSize: {
        width: width,
        height: height
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeSize(e) {
      // to() is a method of `Konva.Node` instances
      e.target.to({
        scaleX: Math.random() + 0.8,
        scaleY: Math.random() + 0.8,
        duration: 0.2
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const vm = this;
    const amplitude = 100;
    const period = 5000;
    // in ms
    const centerX = vm.$refs.stage.getStage().getWidth() / 2;

    const text = this.$refs.text1.getStage();

    // example of Konva.Animation
    const anim = new Konva.Animation(function(frame) {
      text.setX(
        amplitude * Math.sin((frame.time * 2 * Math.PI) / period) + centerX
      );
    }, text.getLayer());

    anim.start();
  }
};
</script>
```

any ideas how I can get the text to appear from outside of the stage and then stop at a certain point within the canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `node.to()` method to animatio any `Konva.Node`:

```
mounted() {
    const textNode = this.$refs.text1.getNode();
    const endX = width / 2 - textNode.width() / 2;
    // run the animation
    textNode.to({
      x: endX,
      onFinish: () => {
        // update the state at the end
        this.textPos.x = endX;
      }
    })
  }
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-konva-animation-demo-lr4qw